# flutter - type file is not a subtype of type 'imageprovider dynamic '

Tags: flutter

When i select image from image picker i am getting this error
type file is not a subtype of type 'imageprovider dynamic '

I tried using stack even though the same error

```
  class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> {
         @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
                title: Text('Profile'),
                centerTitle: true,
                elevation: 10.0,
              ),
              body: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: _imageFile == null
                            ? AssetImage('assets/tom.jpg')
                            : _imageFile,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                child: ListView(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.4,
                    ),
                    Card(
                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                      child: cameraAndEdit(context),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      color: Colors.white70,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            box(),
                            line(color: Colors.deepPurple, lineHeight: 5.0),
                            // nameDesignation(),
                            infoRow(
                                infoIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
                                infoText: 'Name',
                                detail: 'Tom Cruise',
                                textColor: Colors.black),
                            Divider(),
                            infoRow(
                                infoIcon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
                                infoText: 'Address',
                                detail: '#9/1 1st main Circle street Bangalore 560-096',
                                textColor: Colors.black),
                            Divider(),
                            infoRow(
                                infoIcon: Icon(Icons.gesture),
                                infoText: 'Age',
                                detail: '25',
                                textColor: Colors.black),
                            Divider(),
                            infoRow(
                                infoIcon: Icon(Icons.phone),
                                infoText: 'Phone',
                                detail: '+91 9148046273',
                                textColor: Colors.black),
                            line(color: Colors.deepPurple, lineHeight: 5.0),
                            box(),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
   image: _imageFile == null
        ? AssetImage('assets/tom.jpg')
        : _imageFile,
```

should be

```
   image: _imageFile == null
        ? AssetImage('assets/tom.jpg')
        : FileImage(_imageFile),
```

Answer (score 11):

If you used [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picke), try the code below.

```
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

PickedFile _imageFile;

image: _imageFile == null
     ? AssetsImage("sample_image_path")
     : FileImage(File(_imageFile.path)),
```

Comment: This one worked for me, thank you Sudesh! 

Answer (score 8):

If you are loading the image from the network and inside a `BoxDecoration`, you need to use `NetworkImage('...')` instead of `Image.network('...')`

Example:

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(image: NetworkImage("imageUrl"),
      fit: BoxFit.cover)
    ),
```

Answer (score 2):

For me this works:

> Replace **AssetImage** with **Image.Asset**

```
image == null
      ? AssetImage('assets/myimage.jpg')
      : Image.file(_image),
```

**Should Be**

```
image == null
      ? Image.asset('assets/myimage.jpg')
      : Image.file(_image),
```

Answer (score -1):

if use a network image as default and you want to get an image from a gallery you can use this

`image:image==null?NetworkImage('your url'):FileImage(image),`

use this function for image pick from a gallery

```
  Future pickImage() async{
try {
  final image=await ImagePicker().pickImage(source:ImageSource.gallery);
  if(image==null) return;

  final imageTemporary=File(image.path);
  setState(() {
    this.image=imageTemporary;
  });
} on Exception catch (e) {
  print('Faield to pick image: $e');
}}
```

Answer (score -2):

To show images from internet use NetworkImage("imageUrl")
For local images use FileImage(_imageFile)